# how to set two ids generator values in hibernate jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am new to hibernate. How do set two auto increment values. Default id is added but i want add one more value

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "idGenerator")
@TableGenerator(name = "idGenerator", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name="id")
private long id;


@Column(name = CODE
private long code;



@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;
```

Here i want add **code** also. How to add?

Comment: to which column you want to add that? is that column part of the primary key?

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski: **code**